# Spark Submit and File system error

Tags: spark-submit

I installed docker/datastax environment on my local machine and I tried to execute my first spark application with command "spark-submit".

The application is very simple, the classic word count example. I have problem with file system access.

The command executed is:

```
sudo /usr/share/dse/bin/dse spark-submit --master dse://172.19.0.8:9042 --verbose  --class it.lslab.spark.WordCount spark.word-count-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

the error received is:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/username/projects/examples/word_count.text does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:606) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:819) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:596) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:140) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:341) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:767) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:108) ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67) ~[hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.1.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:245) ~[spark-core_2.11-2.0.2.6-de611f9.jar:2.0.2.6-de611f9]
```

Could you please help me?

Thanks
L

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the file named '/home/username/projects/examples/word_count.text' is not exists on all worker nodes.